# Make different changes in each line of bash script based on a list file

Tags: xml, bash, sublimetext3, bioinformatics

I am putting together a list of URLs that include XML snippets, to later run wget on. Each URL only have a little difference from each other, and I have a list of those different values to fill in. Is there an easy way to change that little bit on each URL to the different values? I know sublime text can change the same thing on different lines to another thing; I am asking if there is a way to do that, except for each line the thing to change into is different.

I am trying to access data from a biology database (Ensembl 97), and one option is to wget an URL they provide that contains XML codes. I want to reuse these codes in the future for different species/genes attributes. For example, now I have the code to run a list of genes to get attributes based on one species (Algerian mouse); I want to change that code and use it for 90 other species.

I have the following code to get the information I want for the species "cabingdonii", identified by the last Attribute name definition at the end of the line:

```
wget -O cabingdonii.txt 'http://www.ensembl.org/biomart/martservice?query=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE Query><Query  virtualSchemaName = "default" formatter = "TSV" header = "0" uniqueRows = "0" count = "" datasetConfigVersion = "0.6" ><Dataset name = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl" interface = "default" ><Filter name = "ensembl_gene_id" value = "ENSG00000196565"/><Attribute name = "ensembl_gene_id" /><Attribute name = "cabingdonii_homolog_orthology_type" /></Dataset></Query>'
```

and I have a list of three other species:
mspretus
vpacos
mmarmota

I want to repeat the wget code three more times, each time change the

```
<Attribute name = "cabingdonii_homolog_orthology_type" />
```

into the attribute name of another species, like:

```
<Attribute name = "mspretus_homolog_orthology_type" />
<Attribute name = "vpacos_homolog_orthology_type" />
<Attribute name = "mmarmota_homolog_orthology_type" />
```

While keeping the rest of the code the same. 
I have tried to run a for loop with python, but all the single and double quotes, as well as the slashes, make it really hard to change, especially in reality the code is much longer than this example.

Comment: Don't use string processing mechanisms. Use `xml` parsing modules e.g. look up `xmlstarlet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using double quotes:

```
$ for F in mspretus_homolog_orthology_type vpacos_homolog_orthology_type mmarmota_homolog_orthology_type ; do echo -n "$F " && wget -q -O - "http://www.ensembl.org/biomart/martservice?query=<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Query  virtualSchemaName = \"default\" formatter = \"TSV\" header = \"0\" uniqueRows = \"0\" count = \"\" datasetConfigVersion = \"0.6\" ><Dataset name = \"hsapiens_gene_ensembl\" interface = \"default\" ><Filter name = \"ensembl_gene_id\" value = \"ENSG00000196565\"/><Attribute name = \"ensembl_gene_id\" /><Attribute name = \"$F\" /></Dataset></Query>" ; done

mspretus_homolog_orthology_type ENSG00000196565 
vpacos_homolog_orthology_type ENSG00000196565   
mmarmota_homolog_orthology_type ENSG00000196565
```

Note: for bioinformatics use https://biostars.org or https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, this works! I did not know that wget would know the entire thing to be a string (since there are a bunch of space in the XML part).

Answer (score 2):

To reduce quoting and escaping problems, it is often helpful to store strings in variables. Then you only have to figure out how to escape for the variable assignment, while using the value elsewhere bypasses unwanted interpretation.

Here's an example:

```sh
whackyprefix='<?xml version="1.0"><Attribute name="'
whackysuffix='" more="...">'

values=( mspretus vpacos mmarmota )

printf "$whackyprefix%s$whackysuffix\n" "${values[@]}"
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"><Attribute name="mspretus" more="...">
<?xml version="1.0"><Attribute name="vpacos" more="...">
<?xml version="1.0"><Attribute name="mmarmota" more="...">
```